# FileNotFoundException when calling C# dll from C++/CLI

Tags: c#, .net, dll, visual-studio-2015, c++-cli

I have a `C# dll`, with some methods, which I am trying to access in my native project with `/CLR` support.

I reference this `DLL` using a `#using` directive, and the `DLL` is recognized and the project compiles.

However, during runtime, I get a `FileNotFoundException`, which is pretty weird since the DLL is present in the source directory of the project.

The`DLL` is compiled in`VS 2015` with .NET Version `4.5.2`. Since I have `CLR` support on my C++ mixed, I have edited the project file to make `TargetFrameworkVersion` as 4.5.2, but still the `runtime` does not work.

Kindly advise on what could be the issue?

**EIDT - ADDED SOME CODE**

**C#**

```
namespace TestManagedLibrary
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public int i;
        public Class1()
        {
            i = 5;
        }

        public int returnValue()
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```

**C++/CLI**

```
#using <TestManagedLibrary.dll>


using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices; // Marshal
using namespace TestManagedLibrary;


ref class ManagedFoo
{
public:
    ManagedFoo()
    {
        Console::WriteLine(_T("Constructing ManagedFoo"));
        Class1 ^testObject = gcnew Class1();
        int a = testObject->returnValue();
    }
};
```

Comment: Could be that the DLL references another DLL & it is that which cannot be found or you have a 32/64bit mismatch : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224134/filenotfoundexception-dll-not-found

Comment: @PaulF No, the C# DLL does not refer to any other library. It is just a very simply library that returns the value of an integer to the calling function. Both calling and called are in x64, and would I not get a BadImageFormat exception if this were the case?

Comment: @MethodMan I have added some code. I am not able to use the debugger to step into the `C#` code, the moment that I try and initialize the `C++/CLI` class object that refers the C# class, I get a `FileNotFoundException'. Both have the same Target Framework. I am able, of course, to see the definition of the` C# `class and its member functions.

Comment: by default without declaring the scope of the variable `i` it's private if I am not mistaken. what if you declare it as `public int i`

Comment: @MethodMan Wouldn't that cause a problem when I actually try and refer the function? In my case I am not able to step into the constructor at all. By the way, I tried it, but it did not work, still file not found.

Comment: "the DLL is present in the source directory of the project".  Well, bad place, the CLR is never going to look for it there.  It belongs in the same directory as the EXE.  If necessary use a post-build event to xcopy the file there.

Comment: @MethodMan Scope of the `i` variable has nothing to do with the problem. First the `i` is not accessed from anywhere besides the class it is defined in and thus it should be private. Second it is generally a bad habit to make public fields.

Comment: @HansPassant OK, turns out you are correct. It should have been in the same location as the EXE. Putting it there, worked immediately, Thanks a lot. If you write it out as a solution, I shall accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to ensure that the `TestManagedLibrary.dll` file is located in a place where [Fusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961162/what-is-fusion-in-net-assembly) could find it. Your first try should be the location of the executable you are running.

One way to handle this is via the reference properties. If the reference to your `TestManagedLibrary.dll` is set with the `copy local` flag than during the build the referenced library is going to be copied from the referenced location to the output directory.

You can enable the internal [fusion logging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx) to find out the details:

1. Run `Developer Command Prompt` with administrative privileges.
2. Run `fuslogvw`
3. In the `Assembly Binding Log Viewer` hit settings and set either `Log bind failures to disk` or `Log all binds to disk`.
4. Start your service
5. Hit `Refresh` in the `Assembly Binding Log Viewer`, pick your executable and hit `View Log`

Answer (score 0):

The compiled `DLL` should have been in the same location as the executable for the `CLR` to search for it. In my case, the `.NET` compiled `DLL` was in the solution folder and not searchable.

Comment: So it is. Thank you.