# FileNotFoundException for a .NET Framework library reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio, filenotfoundexception

Getting a `FileNotFoundException` for a reference to a .NET Framework 4.6.2 library out of a .NET Framework 4.6.2 library that was loaded by a .NET 5 project.

Tried all known solutions:

- [FileNotFoundException (DLL not found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224134/filenotfoundexception-dll-not-found)
- [How to enable assembly bind failure logging (Fusion) in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net)
- https://web.archive.org/web/20131212004447/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57120.aspx
- [FileNotFoundException when loading dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503429/filenotfoundexception-when-loading-dll)

Interestingly, the Fusion Log does not list any access attempt to the problematic dll file.

Compiled the project via `Rebuild`, nothing helped.

Comment: Did you check if it is in the output folder for .net5, or if it is in the target framework folder for net462?

Comment: How are you referencing the library? I think more details are needed. The posts linked are about unmanaged DLLs I think, but this is .NET referencing which is a different mechanism.

Comment: yes, it was linked as managed dll and the dll was copied to the output folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having created a completely new library and placed only the isolated method there that needs to be accessed and the error reoccurred also, it was clear, that this isn't a setup problem.

Solved this problem with the `Clean Solution` command!

This command is available:

- in the context menu of the solution entry in the `Solution Explorer`
- in the `Build` menu of visual studio

Comment: You could mark it as the answer.